# Lubuntu: text on system menus/bars appears blurred when memory usage is high

Tags: graphics, fonts, ram, antialiasing

I have an old system (Core 2 Duo 2.0 GHz, 3 GB RAM), running Lubuntu 14.10. When I run memory intensive applications, the text on title-bars, menu-bars and notification panels appears extremely blurry -- almost unreadable.

A few observations:

1. If I highlight the text using mouse drag, the text becomes readable.
2. If I reduce the memory usage, the text remains blurry.
3. If I toggle antialiasing setting in `lxappearance`, the text becomes normal again.

Screenshot with high memory usage:
[image]

Screenshot after reducing memory load and turning off antialiasing (the situation improves somewhat, but not completely):
[image]

Comment: Any before/after screenshots? Or does taking a screenshot from within Lubuntu result in only the "correct" image being saved? And probably not the problem, but maybe testing ram (the boot entry from a live iso works great) is a good idea just in case