# Graphic aberrations when swapping

Tags: graphics, ram, swap

Ever since I started to use Ubuntu on my ThinkPad X200, I have noticed that in certain situations certain graphical elements (desktop backgrounds, button icons, text) will become distorted. You can see the effect in the screen shot below. I am currently running 15.04, but had the same problem with 14.04.

[image: Messed up graphics]

I have found several posts here, like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/565372/lubuntu-text-on-system-menus-bars-appears-blurred-when-memory-usage-is-high), but have not found a solution. I have however, made an observation that might help to diagnose the problem. Others have noted that the issue occurs with high memory usage. Recently I have installed [this amazing gnome-shell extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/120/system-monitor/), and using that extension, I realized that the problem seems to appear as soon as I start swapping. I realize that high memory usage and swapping coincide, but it seems to be the swapping specifically that causes it for me. To test this theory, I lowered my swappiness value to 0 with the command:

```
$ sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=0
```

And had less issues with it than ever, presumably because I was swapping less often (it was set to Ubuntu default 60 before this) - although the problem did return once I eventually started swapping again (3GB of RAM on this computer). Also, I noticed that I could make the problem go away by turning swap on and off with `swapoff -a` and then `swapon -a` as root. Although I have lessened the problem quite a bit, I am still curious about two things:

1. Does this diagnosis make sense, and if so, why would using swap affect the graphics in such a way? It seems like once it starts swapping it is taking memory that is meant for graphics, but I don't know enough about Linux yet to know how to check/stop something like that.
2. If this sounds way off, do you have any other guesses what could be going wrong?

It is a point of pride for me recently to be completely off OS X which I used for about 15 years before switching over completely to Ubuntu about 6 months ago, and I couldn't be happier with Ubuntu, and the Linux community in general, but this has been the one sticking point for me. I am sure this has more to do with my old hardware (which otherwise runs Linux flawlessly) than anything else, and is not a failing of Ubuntu, but I am just hoping that someone out there will have a solution or at least a suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: This looks like a graphics hardware or driver issue. Can you confirm Ubuntu version, and if it happens on a live CD or fresh install, and does it happen with other OSes?  Have you done any other configuration changes particularly to graphics since installation?

Comment: Graphics glitching whenever your computer is doing disk or memory transfers is not that unusual when you have issues like this; as you probably know, turning off swap or reducing swappiness is not a proper solution, it may just mask the problem a bit by making your laptop use its memory or disk less.  Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: Thank you @thomasrutter. I am currently running 15.04, but had the same problem with 14.04 immediately after fresh installation. I also experienced the issue in both gnome-shell and unity, and on an hdd and an ssd in the same computer (not at the same time - I replaced the hdd with an ssd a while back). Any idea of things I might be able to check/commands I could run to help diagnosis? To my knowledge, I haven't installed additional drivers other than those that come default on Ubuntu. Could it be a driver I am missing or one that I am using but shouldn't be?

Answer (score 0):

This problem appears in kernel versions < 3.19
Try to install latest stable kernel with this:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```